# Outlook 365 Accessing Calendars in Service Account via REST API

Tags: rest, outlook, calendar, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I have set up an office 365 Service Account with several calendars linked.  when I get a list of calendars or calendargroups from the REST API the linked calendars do not show up, though they are clearly there in the web interface under 'Your Calendars'  the only groups I get back are 'My Calendars' and 'Other Calendars'  what am I missing?

Comment: When you say "linked", what does that mean? Are these other people's calendars that have granted the service account access to their calendar?

Comment: I guess linked is not the right word, I'm impersonating other email accounts

Comment: The REST API requires OAuth, so there isn't a concept of impersonation. How are you authenticating?

Comment: I"m doing basic Authentication, I know it's going to be depricated but for now I'm using it.   I'm doing impersonation on an Exchange server using NTLM authentication and the EWS api.   Does Office 365 have a EWS interface?

Comment: Yes, EWS is supported on Office 365, and EWS supports impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

The question of your authentication aside, the way you access calendars that other people have shared with you via the REST API is to access it in their mailbox.

So if bob@example.com shared his calendar with you, you would have to do:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/bob@example.com/events
```

There is no way to get a list of all the calendars shared with you, so you would need to either know that before hand or prompt the user to provide the information.

Comment: That's interesting, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Ok I went over to the office OAuth sandbox and tried this but I'm getting a 404 items not found, our IT guys told me that they set up the Service Account and granted access the other accounts I need to get at.

Comment: I went ahead and used the EWS api and now all is well.   it only requests Basic Authentication is that going to stay that way or will it also be deprecated like for the REST API?